# Dynamic queryset using request.POST data in class-based generic views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

I'm interested in how to make dynamic queryset using request.POST query dict? When I did that:

```
class ListCv(ListView):
    queryset = CV.objects.all()
    template_name = 'jobseek/applicants_resumes_list.html'  
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListCv, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['main_form'] = FilterCV(self.request.POST or None)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        main_form = FilterCV(request.POST or None)

        if main_form.is_valid():
            cleaned_fields = main_form.cleaned_data                 

            query_tag = cleaned_fields.get('query_tag')            

            lookup = (~Q(position__icontains=query_tag)| 
                      ~Q(additional_information__icontains=query_tag)|
                      ~Q(title__icontains=query_tag))
            return CV.objects.filter(lookup)
        return CV.objects.all()
```

I have got blank white page without any exceptions. Can I use FormMixin, ProcessFormView for solve my issue? If I can, how?

## edit

template:

```
<div class="vacancies_list">
    {% for object in object_list %}               
        <div class="vacancy">
           <div class="title"><a href="{% url view_cv object.id %}" title="">{{     object.title }}</a></div>
           <div class="body">
           {{ object.employment_type }}; 
           {% for education in object.highereducation_set.all %}
           {{ education.faculty }}: {{ education.specialty }}
           {% endfor %}
           {% for experience in professionalexperience_set.all %}
           {{ experience.company_name }}: {{ experience.position }}
           {% endfor %}...
           &nbsp;<a href="{% url view_cv object.id %}" title="" class="more">Полное     описание<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/arrow_right_green.png" alt=">" title="" /></a>
           </div>
        </div>
     {% endfor %}       
  </div>
```

Comment: "I have got blank white page without any exceptions." would seem to suggest it's problem with your template. Might want to post that too.

Comment: It is not, because without request calling it works good. I'll post the template in a few minutes.

Comment: Chris, I understand what you mean! Maybe that is problem with template look up in the class. But I still don't get how to solve it. Because, as I said - it's works good without request.POST calling.

Comment: Nothing jumps out as "wrong" so this is probably one of those scenarios where something is not returning something you expect it to. Add the line `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` to your `get_queryset` method and step through the code (by typing "next") and check each variable as it's set. Try `CV.objects.filter(lookup)` as well before you step past the return line of the method. That should give you something to work from.

Comment: In particular, I'm thinking your queryset is coming up empty each time, and with your current template, that would result in nothing being displayed. Basically, you need to determine why nothing is being matched by your lookup.

Comment: From a glance I notice you add the tilde (~) to the beginning of each Q() for the lookup. This is negation, so you are saying lookup something that doesn't have the query_tag in it for each field. Maybe this is what you intend, but it just caught my eye initially.

Comment: I had the [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15468246/41948) but it turned out to be a nginx+uWSGi bug.