# django class based view returns empty string when POST

Tags: python, django, post, django-views, django-class-based-views

To demostrate:

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class TestView(View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('haha')
```

urls.py is

```
url(r'^test/', TestView.as_view()),
```

so when GET you can see `haha`, but when doing POST you get a blank page...

What am I missing here?

Edit: To clarify what I am doing. I am writing a JSON stream CURD view, which I need to parse JSON in various ways. One of them is when ppl POST data with certain pattern the view will dispatch to another method inside the view and return something. But it turns out returns nothing instead. So I present you the minimal PoC. Please help me what my code wenti wrong. TIA!

btw [possible related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8216980/41948)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, this is a bug in uWSGI and nginx ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11115108/41948

I am really sorry for wasting your time by misleading you. And still it took me a while to figure which part of my stack went wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You need to implement its `post` method. See [Class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#view).

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class TestView(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return super(TestView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       # do somthing

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

See more for `dispatch` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch).

> The default implementation will inspect the HTTP method and attempt to delegate to a method that matches the HTTP method; a GET will be delegated to get(), a POST to post(), and so on.

So previously you was disturbing the above logic, calling `super` will allow `dispatch` to delegate to post method.

Comment: But I need to rewrite my own dispatch logic, and adding `def post` won't work either.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but what's the difference by directly return HttpResponse in `dispatch()` ? I provided a minimal POC in my question . Which in my case the dispatch handles more than `get` or `post`, but apparently no matter what I put in to HttpResponse  it always returns empty body.

Comment: Try a return in "do something" and POST the URL, you will get blank page... and I can' tell why even looking through the django source code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but it may offer a workaround.  What I have used in JSON applications is to send a post to the get method when I want the same results for both.  Something like:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse('Ha!')

def post(self. request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

with dispatch left alone.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach when using class-based views is not to write your own method handlers from scratch; instead, use one of the generic classes as the base and then modify just the methods which handle what you need. For example, if you have a form which needs to be submitted via POST, you should use the [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#formview) as a base, which handles responses both GET and POST requests.

You don't need to override `post()` and/or `get()` methods themselves; instead use `form_valid()` to define what happens when the form is submitted:

```
class TestView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm
    success_url = "/your/return/url/"
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # do something
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Yes thanks I am aware of that. In my case the upload is not a form, but pure JSON data (the COntent-Type is application/json), I wrote my own JSONCURDView need very much know why the django returns a blank page given `dispatch` returned.

Comment: As ahsan said, that's probably because you have overriden dispatch, so your post or get methods are never called. Call `super` as he did to reinstate the default behaviour.

Comment: Hmm if I explicitly return in `disptch()` why do we need `self.get()` or `self.post()` again? The default behavior has been overriden already.

Comment: To answer that in more detail we should dig into the Django code, but it's always better to follow the way how the application is designed instead of looking for shortcuts. In my experience, hacking directly into `dispatch` can lead to some unpredictable side effects; I'd recommend you to first try to exhaust all the standard approaches (in this case, using some of the many methods that handle the class-based view behaviour) and resort to low-level changes only as a last resort.

Comment: Hi, I dug into Django source and straced every system call, found out it was a nginx+uWSGi bug. See my answers below.